# Raw Input and keys handling on Windows 7

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-7-x64

From the documentation:

> ... If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the message to the next hook. However, **on Windows 7 and later, the hook is silently removed without being called**. There is no way for the application to know whether the hook is removed.
>
> ... In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, it **should monitor raw input instead**. This is because raw input can asynchronously monitor mouse and keyboard messages that are targeted for other threads more effectively than low level hooks can

Ok, but if I need to handle (freeze) a key (e.g. handle=true with keyboard hook), how can I do it by raw input?

Answer (score 2):

If your design is based on **SetWindowsHookEx**, you should have somewhere a function that process your incoming key (In my case, function is named **KeyboardProc** that returns an integer (used in conjunction with **KBDLLHookProc**.

In my case, to prevent the key from being returned, for instance to use in a custom hotkey that I want to trap and consume internally without writing to the active application, I return **1** to that function. **1** will block input. **0** will pass through and send the key.

In my case, I created a class with a property **BlockInput** to block a key passing through the hook when needed (I use a low-level keyboard hook to register unusual hotkeys combinations).

```
 Private Function KeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
 ''' Processing here
 Return If(BlockInput, 1, CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam))
 End function
```

Comment: My question was different.

I ask how to "freeze" a key using **Raw INPUT**. 

If I use RAW INPUT I don't use SetWindowsHookEx nor CallNextHookEx, due to the problems that these APIs have with Windows7.